# Background image in mobile is lost

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, touch

I want to have a background image, which displays nicely in a desktop. However, in small screens, the right part of the picture overflows, causing its content to be lost.

This is the code:

```
body {
  background: url("..") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/79k5z8yf/1/).

I would like to get the whole picture in the mobile screen OR to get all the right part of it and lose some of the left part, which has nothing important. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `center center` you need `center right`.
For some reason that I don't get it doesn't work in the JSFiddle, but it should work in real life...